# How to reuse react route dom Link's to parameters to onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom `Link` and `NavLink` v5 and want to short circuit the `to` parameter values to pass to the `onClick`.

Here is my situation:

In my application - so far only the `to` parameter is used for react Link and NavLink.
However I have a new requirement that I need to send some events to the outer iFrame while clicking the Link or NavLink.

So far my code was like this:

```js
const addVolumeLink = location => ({
    pathname: location.pathname + "/add-volume",
    state: {
        from: location.pathname
    }
});

<Link to={addVolumeLink}>New volume</Link>
```

However when user is clicking on the New Volume, I also need to send an event to the outer iFrame. So naively I altered this code as follows by adding the `onClick` listerner.

```js
const addVolumeLink = location => ({
    pathname: location.pathname + "/add-volume",
    state: {
        from: location.pathname
    }
});

export const nagivateToParentiFrame = (payload) => {
    window.parent.postMessage({
        type: 'SERVICE:NAVIGATE',
        payload,
    }, "*")
};

<Link to={addVolumeLink} 
      onClick={() => nagivateToParentiFrame({
               pathname: `${window.location.pathname}/add-volume`,
               state: {from: window.location.pathname}})}>
       New volume
</Link>
```

What I am looking for: if there is a way to short-circuit the `to` parameter to the onClick. (note: it's a function call here that uses location .. can be a function call or can be an object as well).
Reason: There are 100 of places this onClick in the code I need to write.
So I am thinking of having my own Link component and just replace the `import` instead of everywhere writing this onClick (as my pathname and state shall be same).

Something like this I tried (which did not worked out):

// The component which is not working.

```js
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

const nagivateToParentiFrame = (payload) => {
    window.parent.postMessage({
        type: 'SERVICE:NAVIGATE',
        payload,
    }, "*")
};

export const StyledLinkWithIframeEvent = ({ children, className, style, color, type, large, disabled, tooltip, to, ...rest }) => {
    return <Link
        to={to}
        onClick={() => nagivateToParentiFrame(to)}
        children={children}
        className={className}
        style={style}
        color={color}
        type={type}
        large={large}
        disabled={disabled}
        tooltip={tooltip}
        rest={rest}>
    </Link>
}
```

The usage of the component:

```js
import {StyledLinkWithIframeEvent as StyledLink} from "./myLink"

const addVolumeLink = location => ({
    pathname: location.pathname + "/add-volume",
    state: {
        from: location.pathname
    }
});

const myMainComponent = () => {
   return (<StyledLink to={addVolumeLink}>
         New volume
   </StyledLink>);
}
```

Comment: "So naively I altered this code as follows by adding the `onClick` listener" - This isn't naive in my opinion. If you need to add an `onClick` handler to do some additional "stuff" then the link is clicked this is how it would be done. I don't exactly understand what you mean by "short-circuit the `to` parameter to the onClick" though. Does the code from the second snippet work and do what you want? It seems like your question is really about getting the code in the third snippet working. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code used in that snippet?

Comment: @DrewReese -  You are correct. The 3rd snippet is where I want to use the values of `to` to pass to the `onClick` such that in all the places I don't need to add `onClick` handler. That's what I meant by "short circuit". Basically will pass in my `StyledLinkWithIframeEvent`  `to` parameter and it will be also used in `onClick'.
Updated the 3rd snippet with minimalistic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom link component that adds its own `onClick` handler that calls your `navigateToParentiFrame` function and is passed the result of the passed `to` prop.

```js
export const navigateToParentiFrame = (payload) => {
  window.parent.postMessage({
    type: 'SERVICE:NAVIGATE',
    payload,
  }, "*")
};
```

```
import { Link as BaseLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { navigateToParentiFrame } from '../path/to/navigateToParentiFrame';

const Link = props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  return (
    <BaseLink
      {...props}
      onClick={navigateToParentiFrame.bind(
        null,
        typeof props.to === "function"
          ? props.to(location)
          : props.to
      )}
    >
      {props.children}
    </BaseLink>
  );
};
```

```
const addVolumeLink = location => ({
  ...location,
  pathname: location.pathname + "/add-volume",
  state: {
    ...location.state,
    from: location.pathname,
  }
});

<Link to={addVolumeLink}>New volume</Link>
```

```js
const {
  BrowserRouter: Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link: BaseLink,
  useLocation,
} = ReactRouterDOM;

const navigateToParentiFrame = (payload) => {
  console.log("window.parant.postMessage", {
    type: 'SERVICE:NAVIGATE',
    payload,
  }, "*");
};

const Link = props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  return (
    <BaseLink
      {...props}
      onClick={navigateToParentiFrame.bind(
        null,
        typeof props.to === "function"
          ? props.to(location)
          : props.to
      )}
    >
      {props.children}
    </BaseLink>
  );
};

const addVolumeLink = location => ({
  ...location,
  pathname: location.pathname + "add-volume",
  state: {
    ...location.state,
    from: location.pathname,
  }
});

//<Link to={addVolumeLink}>New volume</Link>

const App = () => {
 return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <BaseLink to="/">Home</BaseLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={addVolumeLink}>New volume</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/add-volume" render={() => <h1>Add Volume</h1>} />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router basename="/js">
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.3.4/react-router-dom.min.js" integrity="sha512-XJ25BbjmZQpaGkOJaDFXVJqfsBebv2aDLsBF3qT6zoC/gVj7XLuefNRzcgmlc5admYuODaYDrap8jzVyOsYFrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="root" />
```